# Selenium - changing Base URL for 1 test isn't applied to others?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I have a test suite with close to 50 test cases.

I want to run the suite against different servers - development, test, production, etc. so I want to be able to change the Base URL for the entire suite easily.

The first step was that I removed this line:

```
<link rel="selenium.base" href="http://dmstaffing-stage.herokuapp.com/" />
```

from every test.

If I change the Base URL for one test however, when I click on the other tests in the Firefox IDE the 'old' URL is still there.

Why doesn't the change get applied to all the tests?

I know that some people have addressed this issue by creating a variable for the Base URL that they then use throughout the test suite.  My question is more "why doesn't selenium apply the change to all cases in all circumstances anyway", as (for example) when you close and re-open selenium it *is* changed for all and is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer turns out to be that the Base URL change **will** get applied to all the other test cases in the suite (those that have had the `<link rel="selenium.base" href="http://dmstaffing-stage.herokuapp.com/" />` line removed.

The 'trick' to it working correctly however, is that you have to either

- open another test suite and then re-open the original suite

or

- close selenium completely and then re-open it and re-open the test suite in question.

After this the you will find that the Base URL has been applied to all the other tests!

So I think this might actually be a bug in the Selenium IDE.

Answer (score 0):

The "Trick" does not work with Selenium 2.0 and Firefox 21: After re-opening, the first script has the new URL, all the other scripts use the old one.

I have a large suite with dozens of testcases, and have been unable to find any convenient way of applying the "Base Url" to all of the scripts in the suite.

If I read the forums right, this has been bugged for a very long time.

Workaround 1:

Open testcase, paste in new URL, save, open next testcase.

Workaround 2:

Use notepad++ or a similar editor to search-and-replace the URL across your scripts.

Comment: Actually I am using selenium 2.0 and Firefox 21 and it is working for me.  It's still a bit flaky.  You have to make sure the Base URL line itself is changed before an exit/reenter.  Sometimes it seems like it's taken a couple of attempts to get changes to stick, but it does work.   I am on Ubuntu 12.04